# Inserting phrases before/after certain letters in strings

Tags: java, string

Hey I'm having another problem with my coding assignment tonight. I'm supposed to write a method to add "bool" in front of every "a" in the passed string s. But my code only adds it to one specific "a". How would a go about fixing this with a while loop. Thanks!

Lets say s=banana

```
public static String insertBool(String s){
    int pos=s.indexOf("a");
    if(pos>-1){
    String firstS=(s.substring(0,pos));
    String secondS=(s.substring(pos, s.length()));
    return(firstS+"bool"+secondS);
    }
    else
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: first - add a while loop.  find each successive occurrence of 'a'

Comment: Why use a `while` loop?

Answer (score 3):

You could just replace all the a's in the string with "boola".

```
public static String insertBool(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("a", "boola");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String.replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
public static String insertBool(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return s.replace("a", "boola");
}
```

Or you could use a more complicated `while` and something like,

```
public static String insertBool(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        return null;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
    while (i < arr.length) {
        if (arr[i] == 'a') {
            sb.append("bool");
        }
        sb.append(arr[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```